# Extract info from files to output with filename concatenated and separeted by commas

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have some directory with multiple files with the extention .failed
This the number of files can change every day.
This files have the following format:

**file1.failed:**

```
FHEAD|4525|20170109000000|20170125024831
THEAD|150001021|20170109121206||
TDETL|4000785067||1|EA|||RETURN|||N
TTAIL|1
THEAD|150001022|20170109012801||
TDETL|4000804525||1|EA|||RETURN|||N
TTAIL|1
FTAIL|6
```

I need to extract all the text between THEAD| and |2 to a output file. im trying the following and it works only if i have only one file in the directory.

```
sed -n 's:.*THEAD|\(.*\)|2.*:\1:p' <*.failed >transactions.log
```

**The output is:
transactions.log:**

```
150001021
150001022
```

Now how can i do the same but for multiple files?(undetermined number of files).

Also it is possible to add the filename in every line of the output file as follows?

**expected output:**

```
file1.failed,150001021
file1.failed,150001022
file2.failed,150001023
file2.failed,150001024
file2.failed,150001025
file2.failed,150001026
file3.failed,150001027
file3.failed,150001028
```

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(tested with `gawk` and `mawk`)

```
awk -F'|' '$1 == "THEAD" {print FILENAME, $2}' OFS=, file*.failed > transactions.log

cat transactions.log 
file1.failed,150001021
file1.failed,150001022
file2.failed,150001023
file2.failed,150001024
file3.failed,150001025
file3.failed,150001026
```

Comment: Hello Master of AWK,
It's exactly that output that i expect.
I will now try to understand it fully.

Best regards,

Comment: @CarlosPinho I cheated a bit - it doesn't exactly extract "text between THEAD| and |2", instead it extracts the second pipe-delimited *field* when the first field matches `THEAD`. If you really need to check that the following field starts with `2`, or if `THEAD` can occur elsewhere in the line, the solution will need adjustment -lmk

Comment: In this case, the files are created automatically so THEAD it only occurs once per line, actually your solution is even better that the initial requirement.

Note that the 2 field stands for the 2 in 2017(current year) it means that your solution will be good even in 3000 year and so on :)